# Using PHP and MySQL, how do you send a variable into a WHERE... IN clause?

Tags: php, mysql

The following SELECT statement works just fine:

```
try {     
  $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT *
                       FROM classes
                       WHERE classes.id IN (65,70,80)');
  $sql->execute();
  $sublist = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

BUT when I try to send a variable into the WHERE clause, I only get one row back.

In this case $ids is a string that looks like '65,70,80'.

```
try {     
  $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT *
                       FROM classes
                       WHERE classes.id IN (?)');
  $sql->bindParam(1, $ids);
  $sql->execute();
  $sublist = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

Do I need to change the way I'm fetching the data, or is my syntax wrong?

---

A-HA!   Thanks for that link Mihai.  Here's the code that works:

First:  instead of passing in a string, put ids into an $ids array.

```
// Figure out how many ? marks have to be in your query as parameter placeholders.
$count = count($ids);
$arrayOfQuestions = array_fill(0, $count, '?');
$queryPlaceholders = implode(',', $arrayOfQuestions);

try {     
  $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT *
                       FROM classes
                       WHERE classes.id IN (' . $queryPlaceholders . ')');
  $sql->execute($ids);
  $sublist = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

Comment: You are binding a string so it will look for `'65,70,80'` Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: if `$ids` is an `array` change your code to `$sql->bindParam(1, implode(',', $ids));`

Comment: What is the type of `$ids`? Array? String?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add an answer. If you have an answer to the question you asked, add it as an *answer* to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {     
  $sql = $db->prepare('SELECT *
                       FROM classes
                       WHERE classes.id IN (?)');
  $sql->bindParam(1, explode(',', $ids));
  $sql->execute();
  $sublist = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  die();
}
```

Comment: When I test this I get an "Array to String Conversion" error.    The question that Mihai refers to above got me on the right track.